# Check fails even if it exists in scala

Tags: java, scala, jsf, gatling

I have recorded a session in scala. One request is failing even though I can see that tag in `View source` and `Inspect Element`. I tried all the other hidden fields but seems this one is not found. Here is the script:

```
val scn = scenario("Scenario Name")
.feed(csv("user_credentials.csv"))
.exec(http("request_1")
.get("/userLogin")
.headers(headers_1) 
.check(regex("""<input id="javax.faces.ViewState" """).saveAs("ViewState_id"))

).pause(1)
.exec(http("request_999")
.post("/userLogin")
.headers(headers_1)
.param("""loginForm""", """loginForm""")
.param("""errorMsg""", """""")
.param("""c_username""", "${username}")
.param("""javax.faces.ViewState""", "${ViewState_id}")
.param("""goButton""", """goButton""")

)
```

The error which I'm getting is,

```
c.e.e.g.h.a.GatlingAsyncHandlerActor - Request 'request_1'
failed : Check 'exists' failed, found None
```

I found the tag `<input id="javax.faces.ViewState" ..../>` in source but this script is not able to find it. I tried testing with other fields and some hidden fields also, all other components are found except this. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `s"${username}"` instead of just `"${username}"`? Scala only does replacement of expressions between `${...}` if you put an `s` in front of the string literal.

Comment: May be,but issue is coming before that.Check is failing as I've shown in the question.Once it passes that statement,I can check for what you are saying.

Comment: `"${username}"` is a Gatling-ism (it has a built-in expression language). The lack of an `s` at the start is normal.

Comment: Have you tried turning on debug logging? Often when this happens, it's a clue that Gatling isn't getting the response you think it's getting.

Comment: Also, I would be tempted to replace the regex search with `css("#javax\\.faces\\.ViewState", "value")`. I don't trust regexes with HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that the `id` of your ViewState object is not actually `javax.faces.ViewState` - the `name` will be `javax.faces.ViewState`, but in the JSF implementations that I've seen, the id is something like `j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0`.

The simplest solution would be to follow the instructions at https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Handling-JSF for handling JSF in Gatling. Or, you could search for the ViewState element by name, rather than id - something like:

```
.check(css("""input[name="javax.faces.ViewState"]""", "value").saveAs("ViewState_id"))
```

Should do the trick.